# Creating a table starting midway on a page, and wrapping to the next in LaTex

Tags: latex, tabular, longtable

I am trying to create a table in LaTex. The two methods for doing this I see involves using tabular or longtable. However they both have different issues I am not sure how to work around.

Longtables are good at handeling tables that extend onto the next page, but they always have to start at the top of a new page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD4Lx.png)

Tabular can start at any point in a page, but they cannot handle wrapping to the next page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4MAU.png)

Is there an easy way to make a table that can start midway on a page, and extend over to the next?

Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think a longtable can't start mid page?

Comment: Please make a [mre] that shows us how you manages to make a longtable not start mid-page

Answer (score 0):

A longtable as such can of course start mid-page:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{longtable}{lr}
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]